# How to add custom input fields into mobile device's setting pages on both android & ios in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have an **expo managed** react native application. In the application, i fetched data from an endpoint. Let's say this endpoint is [www.cloud.my-company.com](http://www.cloud.my-company.com) . To exemplify, i have 2 different customers and those customers should be connected my application from different endpoints such that first of my customer should use [www.first-customer.cloud.my-company.com](http://www.first-customer.cloud.my-company.com) and second of my customer should use [www.second-customer.cloud.my-company.com](http://www.second-customer.cloud.my-company.com) . What i trying to do is that add an input box to setting page of the customers mobile devices so that user can enter their own customer endpoints. However, i could not find any documentation about expo or react native. I provide a picture of the existing app that can able to do that feature.

I searched from the internet but cannot find any solutions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5NCU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be able to achieve the intended behaviour. Also, it is not good UX to let your users decide what URL to use. This is also a huge security risk.

Having said that, adding a custom input in your OS settings is only [possible on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html). For this you'll have to eject the project from Expo.

You're better off using [environment variables in your project](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=performancemax&gclid=CjwKCAjwkLCkBhA9EiwAka9QRvxj3OElW3m3nCuzifDnChCV-vl_38YZp9GqY9PBRU6CSeqktZYmHBoCnlMQAvD_BwE) and give your users an option to switch between environments/backends using a setting inside your app.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It seems that i'm going to use that way